# Get parametric bilinear form given the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 2x2 matrix (over real numbers) which represents a symmetric bilinear form. Is there a way to get the parametric form (i just assume the std base)?

Comment: What do you mean by parametric form?

Comment: For example f(x,y) = x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, what it means for a matrix to represent a bilinear form is that $$f(x,y) = x^\top Ay$$

So if $x = [x_1, x_2]^\top$ and $y = [y_1,y_2]^\top$, and $A = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a & c \\
     b & d
  \end{array} \right]$ then

$$f(x,y) = [x_1, x_2] \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a & b \\
     b & d
  \end{array} \right] [y_1,y_2]^\top = ax_1y_1+cx_1y_2+bx_2y_1+dx_2y_2$$